# have trouble with PIL to create PhotoImage object

Tags: python

I have Python 2.6 running on Fedora 13. I installed PIL 1.1.7, and I get the successful installed message in the Python prompt. I am able to import `PIL.PhotoImage`,but when I try to run the following, I get an error.

```
mgobj = PhotoImage(file=imgpath)
```

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "viewer-tk.py", line 25, in <module>
    imgobj = PhotoImage(file=imgpath)        # now JPEGs work!
File "/home/Toshiba/vinpython/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 116, in __init__
    self.paste(image)
File "/home/Toshiba/vinpython/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 181, in paste
    import _imagingtk
ImportError: No module named _imagingtk
```

In the module `ImageTk.py` , I see `_imagingtk` being imported,but i am not sure how do it get that module.Help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: just a hunch...what happens if you try `import Tkinter` from the command prompt?

Comment: I am getting the same import error. Tkinter works fine?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install [Tkinter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) python module as stated at this [trac](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/28265). But since it's [an integral part of python distributions](ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/python/topics/tkinter/download.html). Since you are using fedora take a look at [this page](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/How_to_install_Tkinter) where you can install Tkinter when it doesn't come along, even being for Fedora 3 I think it might help.